# Mongodb search element

Tags: mongodb, object, search, aggregate

I have this following result:

```
    "res" : [
            {
                "_id" : "1", 
                "name" : "Pierre", 
                "lstname" : "Jean", 
                "val" : [
                    {
                        "nameval" : "opae", 
                        "valval" : 8
                    }, 
                    {
                        "nameval" : "gpke", 
                        "valval" : 7
                    }
                ], 
                "date_arrivee" : ISODate("2018-09-03T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "2", 
                "name" : "Patrick", 
                "lstname" : "Bruno", 
                "val" : [
                    {
                        "nameval" : "azerzer", 
                        "valval" : 6
                    }, 
                    {
                        "nameval" : "gpke", 
                        "valval" : 9
                    }
                ], 
                "date_arrivee" : ISODate("2018-09-05T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }
        ]
```

I would like have this instead: (The nameval in val should be equals to "gpke" and I need the id of element).

```
    {
       "_id": 1,
       "nameval": "gpke",
       "valval": 7
    },
    {
       "_id": 2,
       "nameval": "gpke",
       "valval": 8
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "res.val.nameval": "gpke"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$res"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$res.val"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "res.val.nameval": "gpke"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": "$res._id",
            "nameval": "$res.val.nameval",
            "valval": "$res.val.valval"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Sure, the first `$match` is just for efficiency otherwise we would `$unwind` the entire collection and not just required documents, then by using `$unwind` we "open up" the arrays making each document have just one inner `val` document. at that point we just have to match whats left. the projection just alters the results structure.